# How to iterate over all the objects received as props from its parent in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using react-accessible-accordion. I want to populate the innermost child component with the data received as props from the parent component.

To do so, I am doing something like below in my respective components:

Parent Component —

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ChildAccordion1 from './ChildAccordion1'


import {
    Accordion,
    AccordionItem,
    AccordionItemTitle,
    AccordionItemBody,
} from 'react-accessible-accordion';


import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/fancy-example.css';
import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/minimal-example.css';


class ParentAccordion extends React.Component {

   getMappedData = () =>{ 
    const myObj = [
        {"Name":"John Doe", "City": "Chicago","ID":1,"address": "207 Mills Town"},
        {"Name":"Ramph Brown", "City": "LA","ID":2,"address":"508 Mills Town"}
    ];
      if (myObj) { 
         return myObj.map(item =>{
             console.log(item);
            return (
                <Accordion>
                    <AccordionItem>
                        <AccordionItemTitle>
                        </AccordionItemTitle>
                        <AccordionItemBody>
                        <ChildAccordion1 {...item} />
                        </AccordionItemBody>
                    </AccordionItem>
                </Accordion>
            )
        })
      }
      else {
          return "";
      }
  }


    render(){
        return (
            // RENDER THE COMPONENT
            <div>
                {this.getMappedData()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}




export default ParentAccordion
```

Here, if you see I am passing only item as props to my child component i.e only objects.

Child Component1 —

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import InnerMostChildComp from './InnerMostChildComp'

import {
    Accordion,
    AccordionItem,
    AccordionItemTitle,
    AccordionItemBody,
} from 'react-accessible-accordion';


import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/fancy-example.css';
import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/minimal-example.css';


class ChildAccordion1 extends React.Component {

    render(){
        const propToChild = this.props;
        return (
            // RENDER THE COMPONENT
            <Accordion>
        <AccordionItem>
            <AccordionItemTitle>
            </AccordionItemTitle>
            <AccordionItemBody>
                <table className="accordionTable">
                    <thead className="row">
                        <th className="col-sm-6">Name</th>
                        <th className="col-sm-6">City</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr className="row">
                            <td className="col-sm-6">Name</td>
                            <td className="col-sm-6">City</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <InnerMostChildComp propFromParent = {propToChild}/>
            </AccordionItemBody>
        </AccordionItem>
    </Accordion>
        );
    }
}

export default  ChildAccordion1
```

InnerMost Child Component —

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {
    Accordion,
    AccordionItem,
    AccordionItemTitle,
    AccordionItemBody,
} from 'react-accessible-accordion';

import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/fancy-example.css';
import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/minimal-example.css';

const InnerMostChildComp = (props) => {
  return (
    <Accordion>
        <AccordionItem>
            <AccordionItemTitle>
                <h4>List</h4>
            </AccordionItemTitle>

            <AccordionItemBody>
                <table className="accordionTable">
                    <thead className="row">
                        <th className="col-sm-2">Name </th>
                        <th className="col-sm-2">City </th>
                        <th className="col-sm-2">Id </th>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        {
                            Object.keys(props.propFromParent).map((key, index) => {
                                console.log(key, index);
                               return (
                                <tr className="row">
                                    <td className="col-sm-2">{props.propFromParent[key].Name}</td>
                                    <td className="col-sm-2">{props.propFromParent[key].City}</td>
                                    <td className="col-sm-2">{props.propFromParent[key].Id}</td>
                                </tr> 
                               )
                            })
                        }  
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </AccordionItemBody>
        </AccordionItem>
    </Accordion>
  )
};

export default  InnerMostChildComp
```

I want each `tr` to have the selected attributes from the objects index wise so to do so, I am using `Object.keys` as the props we get in child is always a component.

Problem I am facing is that in my InnerMostChildComp, in my props.propsfromParent, I get first object of an array i.e object related to ID 1 and then when I put debugger on td, it appears that instead of iterating through the number of objects I have in my array which is 2, it is iterating over all the individual attributes(keys and values) of my first object and it prints all the keys and values. Then the control goes back again to props.propsfromParent where my second object is displayed and again the iteration happens inside the same object over the keys and values which is not what I want. For instance, when I debug my InnerMostChildComp, Object.keys iterates over each attributes of the first object instead of iterating over both the objects. My props.propFromParent does show the second object after the iteration of first object gets completed.Probably I am not using the Object.keys right way or the problem is with my props.propFromParent.

Comment: Well, only one of the `propFromParent` is indexed. But the first parameter to the `map` function is the object, not the index (`index` is the second param, the collection is the third). It's not a terribly useful property name, either.

Comment: Moreover, only first `td` uses  `[index].key1` while on other `td`s just `key2` and so on.

Comment: @extempl yeah I have tried both the ways but neither of them are working so have added both in tr for reference.

Comment: @DaveNewton property name I have jus added for dummy.Yes  only one of the propFromParent is indexed. I am trying to fix it not sure how can I fix this.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I am wondering how its just getting one object.

Comment: Could you add the value of the `propFromParent` prop?

Comment: @extempl propsFromParent is the first object of my array.

Comment: @extempl My parent has array of objects.I am passing only objects as props to my child components. So my child comp has the actual object from parent.

Comment: Instead of trying to explain with words, show actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**
It is hard to understand what you want to get in the result, so to keep it simple, your table (presumably) should look like the following:

```
const myObj = [
  { Name: 'John Doe', City: 'Chicago', ID: 1 },
  { Name: 'Ramph Brown', City: 'LA', ID: 2 } // Note `Name` here instead of your `accessKey`
];

<table className="accordionTable">
  <thead className="row">
  <th className="col-sm-2">Name</th>
  <th className="col-sm-2">City</th>
  <th className="col-sm-2">Id</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {myObj.map(item => {
      return (
      <tr className="row">
        <td className="col-sm-2">{item['Name']}</td>
        <td className="col-sm-2">{item['City']}</td>
        <td className="col-sm-2">{item['ID']}</td>
      </tr>
      )
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT 2:**

So, `propFromParent` is equal to `{Name: "John Doe", City: "Chicago", ID: 1}`. Therefore, this:

```
<tbody>
{
  Object.keys(props.propFromParent).map((key, index) => {
    console.log(key, index);
    return (
      <tr className="row">
        <td className="col-sm-2">{props.propFromParent[key].Name}</td>
        <td className="col-sm-2">{props.propFromParent[key].City}</td>
        <td className="col-sm-2">{props.propFromParent[key].Id}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
}
</tbody>
```

should be changed to this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr className="row">
    <td className="col-sm-2">{props.propFromParent.Name}</td>
    <td className="col-sm-2">{props.propFromParent.City}</td>
    <td className="col-sm-2">{props.propFromParent.ID}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

This will fix the table in the nested accordion, but still, you'll have two accordion components per row (so, you'll always have one row per table per accordion (as layout built)).

**EDIT 3:**

In result, you should get rid of first iteration and just pass entire array into the Child Accordion component like `<ChildAccordion1 myObj={myObj} />` and then just iterate it in the `InnerMostChildComp` with

```
<tbody>
{
  props.propFromParent.myObj.map(item => {
    return (
      <tr className="row">
        <td className="col-sm-2">{item.Name}</td>
        <td className="col-sm-2">{item.City}</td>
        <td className="col-sm-2">{item.ID}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
}
</tbod
```

Comment: if I do prop.propsfromParent[key], I understand it will display all of the keys of my object. What if I want to display only Id and Name from the object I have? I would have to pick those keys right.

Comment: @techiequestie Then you do not want to `iterate` over them. Just render two components with `Id` and `Name` separately

Comment: @techiequestie Something like this: `<InnerMostChildComp key='Id' value={propToChild.Id} />
<InnerMostChildComp key='Name' value={propToChild.Name} />`
I also updated the answer.

Comment: I did not quite understand it. If I add the value in InnerMostChildComp then do I need to remove the object.keys from InnerMostChildComp? Also, how will I render the tr td structure?

Comment: @techiequestie Please check recent updates. This should do the trick for a table rendering, but it does not solve the accordion mess. I think it should not be hard to integrate this into any accordion logic you would need

Comment: It does not solve my problem sadly. The real problem I am facing is to have the accordion component rendered in my child accordion component. I have tried these ways but this doesn't seem to work out.Thanks for trying it though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181843/discussion-between-extempl-and-techie-questie).

Comment: Solution is working fine with EDIT3. Marking this as completed.